# How to use a custom id when post an article in WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

WordPress' post_id is not continuous, so I want to use a custom post_id in wordpress when post an article.

For example, I want to post an article as |id=2`in database wp_posts, I got the position of`id=1` , what do I need to do in my function? I add it to my theme's functions.php

```php
function reuse_old_id(){
    global $wpdb;
    $lastID = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT ID FROM (SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts ORDER BY ID ASC) T WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE ID=T.ID-1) LIMIT 1");
    $lastID++;
    // I tried the following code but the it didn't work
    $wpdb->query("ALTER TABLE $wpdb->posts AUTO_INCREMENT = $lastID");
}
```

Comment: what exactly do you want? post_id, do you mean ID in wp_posts?

Comment: Without knowing to much about your actual intention, this approach seems to open the door for a lot of issues. Post id doesn't seem to be continous since wordpress creates revisions of your posts, so "subsequent" posts (in means of their creation date) don't have to have directly adjacent ids like 1,2,3. Altering a central table of wordpress manually will cause you a lot of troubles.

Comment: @ fmsthird yean, I mean post_id as ID in table wp_posts, sorry about my expression

Comment: @mynd thanks, I got an idea that I pass a parameter(post_id) to the default post function, thus subsequent troubles can be avoided.